# Programmatic Signing of Native Windows Mobile Apps

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, signing, certificate-authority

Is there any certificate authority that allows for programmatic signing of windows mobile applications?  At the moment my team uses Geotrust.  Our build procedure looks like this:

- Build app
- "pre-sign" app with multi-step tool (
- fill out form and upload "pre-signed" app on geotrust web site
- download signed app
- repeat

There must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/products-services/security-services/code-signing/microsoft-smartphone-code-signing/features-benefits.html) provide a SOAP API that you can automate for M2M signing when using the "new" signing procedures.

The company I work for use Verisign using the old method and we build a application to automate the web forum filling out and uploading which worked ok.  We are in the middle of re-writing to use the SOAP API instead under the new M2M signing rules.